# codename one date time picker components editable

Tags: codenameone, datetimepicker, contenteditable

Currently we are using date with time picker, We looking the updated feature on this date time picker when user try to edit and type his/her own Date or Hours or Minutes or AM/PM component.

Clients posted the issues regarding this date time picker.Any updated tool is available on this date time picker?

please help us or guide us how to achieve this.

Comment: You say that issues were posted on this.  Are these in the CN1 issue tracker?  If so, please provide a link in your question.  I'm not sure I understand the problem you are having.  Please elaborate.  Snippets of code can help to understand what you are trying to achieve.